# FME - Filter Parameter choices to only projected coordinate systems

Tags: python, fme-form, parameters, validation

I have an FME workspace in which the user sets several parameters before running.  One of the parameters is a Coordinate System.

[image]

I would like the user to choose only Projected Coordinate Systems as the rest of the workbench is dependent on it. I want this to happen before running the workbench.  Kind of like a validation.

I was thinking a Python Startup Script to only make the projected coordinate systems available.  But I'm unsure how to do that.

I'm comfortable with a Python solution if that's the only way.

Comment: Is there a fixed number of projections that could possibly selected (if so just make it a predefined choice parameter) or do you really need to allow every PCS under the sun? Also see my answer to your other question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/97762/753

Comment: Thanks @blah238, I thought about using a drop down choice. I'm in Australia and there are probably less than 10 to choose from. However, we do some international work sometimes, and I thought it might be useful to allow other PCSs.  I recently did some tool validation in ArcGIS and was hoping for something similar.  I suppose it is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new user parameter of type "Choice with Alias". Then under the configuration dialog select Import > Coordinate Systems from the menu that is available. Then you can pick whatever coordinate systems you want to make available to the user.

The remaining task is to link that user parameter to the FME parameter for coordinate system (whether you use the Writer parameter or a transformer).

Answer (score 0):

You could not worry about the coordinate system chosen, and just do a reprojection in the workflow. That would ensure that your workspace functions properly.

Comment: The reprojection does occur in the workflow.  However, this is a generic workflow that reprojects a pipeline and all the data that goes with it.  I want the projection to be a parameter at the beginning so all other data reprojects to the same projection.  I don't want to hard code the projection because different pipelines exist in different areas of the globe.

Comment: If you leave the projection out, the workflow will pick it up automatically from the dataset. Is it likely that you will encounter data that has no projection defined?

Comment: No, it's unlikely that there will be undefined projections.  However, it is likely that the input will be in a geographic coordinate system.  I need to force a projected coordinate system, hence the input parameter.