# FME - Conditionally make parameters visible

Tags: python, fme-form, parameters, validation

I have an FME workspace in which the user sets several parameters before running.  The first parameter is a multiple choice where the user selects which layers they would like to process.
Depending on which options they choose, different WorkspaceRunner transformers are run.

[image]

There are additional parameters that feed into the other Workspace Runners.  However, I don't want them to be visible unless the relevant options are chosen in the first parameter.

[image]

Essentially, if someone selects "03 ROW Width" in the first parameter, then I want the associated parameter below (`[03] Easement Width (L : R)`) to appear.  Likewise, if the user selects "08 Minimum Cover" in the first parameter, then I want the associated parameter below (`[08 Depth of Cover (mm)`).  If they deselect those options, the associated parameters turn off.

Is this possible?  Does FME support validation in this way?

I'm open to a python solution if this can only be done in a startup script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call these "Active Choice" parameters in FME. At the moment they are not available to users, but we plan to expose them (I see a comment that it's planned for FME2015, but I don't know how reliable that is).

fyi: It's filed as PR#36909 so I will add a comment and link to this question and increase the priority of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this can't be done within FME workspaces. There just isn't any kind of API provided for parameter UI/validation, and the built-in validation and parameter types/controls are pretty limiting.

I don't think you necessarily want to try to make your FME workspaces too "smart" anyways -- just provide the minimal number of parameters needed for it to function correctly.

If you need more control, create a separate controller application (could be almost anything, really, a Python/Java/.NET desktop app, a web app, mobile app, etc.) and implement the user interface and validation you require. After validating the user input, the app then calls `fme.exe` or FME Server to run the workspace and do the work.

If you have FME Server this also means your users don't each need an FME Desktop license + installation just to run this workspace.